# CloudFront Static Hosting on S3 with a Load Balanced API in a Custom Origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront

I'm playing around with CloudFront and I'm running into an issue with a custom origin. I've got my frontend, which are all statics, on S3. CloudFront is serving those up just fine. When I set up a new behavior to route to my backend API behind a load balancer, CloudFront isn't actually routing the traffic. The Path Pattern and the Origin are defined correctly - it's just not routing.

I can hit my frontend at:

https://somerandomstring.cloudfront.net/apps/myapp/resources/index.html

When logging in, it attempts to POST to `/myapi/rest/Login?<some_query_string>`

I've got both origins configured in CloudFront.

```
+---------------------------+------------+-------------+---------+
| Origin                    |            | Origin | Protocol     |
| Name/Path                 | ID         | Type   | Policy       |
+===========================+============+========+==============+
| mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com | S3-origin  | S3     | None         |
| myelb.amazonaws.com       | ELB-origin | Custom | Match Viewer |
+---------------------------+------------+--------+--------------+
```

And I've got my Behaviors configured.

```
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+
|               |            | Viewer              | Query       |
|      Pattern  |   Origin   | Protocol Policy     | Strings Fwd |
+===============+============+=====================+=============+
| /myapi/rest/* | ELB-origin | Redir HTTP to HTTPS | Yes         |
| Default       | S3-origin  | Redir HTTP to HTTPS | Yes         |
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+

Side note: I spent entirely too much time formatting those tables...
```

When the static frontend attempts to POST to `/myapi/rest/Login?<some_query_string>`, I'm getting a 502:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|                           Name                            | Status |
+===========================================================+========+
| https://cname.cloudfront.net/myapi/rest/Login?<query_str> |    502 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

A `curl -i` returns the following:

```
HTTP/2 502 
content-type: text/html
content-length: 587
server: CloudFront
date: Fri, 15 Dec 2017 21:38:13 GMT
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 861354a025845bd3b87dc25ce80431df.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: XKj4fuF6qGAQd-JBIftvUhoAh5SPnzqBOT2HwUQiMIruqiIJhZ5fuw==

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: vEQTkS9fmjfQqlWA4ICS62DOLTHps-6wjeVWKvBz0XTNex39Um_wjQ==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY>
```

There are no longs on the backend of anything hitting the server and there's nothing helpful in the CloudFront logs either. I can however, POST directly to my load balancer `https://myelb.amazonaws.com/myapi/rest/Login?<some_query_string>` just fine. At this point, I'm completely stumped. I'd really like to avoid using something like Nginx if at all possible.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: "CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin." Leads me to believe it may be Network ACL/Security Group or routing issue that's preventing CloudFront from connecting to your ELB.

Comment: I had considered the security groups as well, but they are wide open at the moment. And the only rules in my ACLs allow everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was an SSL cert issue. I had the wrong cert attached to the load balancer, which was throwing the 502.

For anyone else that may run into this, double check your certs. And also make sure your ciphers are compatible.

Comment: See [HTTP Status Code 502 (Bad Gateway)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html) in the CloudFront Developer Guide for these and other possible causes.